# How to simplify this ActiveRecord eager-load query?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, eager-loading

In a project of mine, I'm using the Ruby ActiveRecord (not a Rails application, though) and I use the following structure:

```
class Customer < ::ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Categories < ::ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :customers
end
```

In one part of the application, I load all the customers to process them and I try to eager-load their relevant categories (within a *ActiveRecord::IdentityMap.use* block):

```
Customer.includes(:categories).all
```

This does what I need to do, but when I look at the resulting eager-load query, it reads like:

```
SELECT "categories".*, "t0"."customer_id" AS ar_association_key_name_customer_id
FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "customers_categories" "t0"
ON "categories"."id" = "t0"."category_id" WHERE
((("t0"."customer_id" = 1) OR ("t0"."customer_id" = 2) OR ("t0"."customer_id" = 3) OR ... ))
```

I am loading all the customers and there is no need to filter them on the join table. There are only several categories, but many customers and the resulting query has thousands of unneeded OR statements.

Is there a way to simplify the query (in the ActiveRecord way) to not include the WHERE conditions in form of customer_id = X ?

Comment: Why do you include `categories` if you don't need them?

Comment: I do need the categories, even though it is not shown in the code above. I just want to simplify the SQL query so that the whole customers_categories table is loaded without using the WHERE clause (which is useless in this case).